# What is the localization of a ring by the whole ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

This question seems quite trivial, but I don't seem to be able to avoid it.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Then trivially $R$ is a multiplicative subset of itself, so we can localize, obtaining $R^{-1} R$. This seems like a silly thing to do, but it came up when I was trying to compute something, so it's not just a silly question for the sake of a silly question.

My question is, does $R^{-1} R$ make sense? I can't see any formal reason why it wouldn't. However, this means we have a multiplicative inverse for zero, which my instincts say is problematic.

Comment: If $S$ contains $0$, then $S^{-1}R$ is the zero ring. If $S$ is all the nonzero elements of $R$, then this is kind of like a field of fractions.

Comment: My initial guess was that it should be the zero ring. Can you explain why?

Comment: Because $0$ is invertible in $R^{-1} R$. Since it annihilates every element, the only way that can be the case is if $0=1$, and then $x=1 \cdot x = 0 \cdot x = 0$ for every $x \in R^{-1} R$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $S$ contains $0$. Then the natural map $R \to S^{-1}R$ sends $0$ to a unit in $S^{-1}R$. Ring homomorphisms always send $0$ to $0$, so $S^{-1}R$ must be a ring where $0$ is a unit. The only such ring is the zero ring, i.e. the ring with one element.